# How do I make a bootable USB stick with Clonezilla manually, using a zip (not ISO)?

Tags: usb-drive, bootable, clonezilla

I want to make a bootable USB stick with Clonezilla. I'll edit some things to use the [preseed](https://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/05_Preseed_options_to_do_job_after_booting) functions, and therefore want to be able to edit files on the stick. Earlier I've printed the Clonezilla ISO on the same stick, and that works great, but now I follow the instructions here:

https://clonezilla.org/liveusb.php
Section: **GNU/Linux Method A: Manual**

I've used `gdisk` to make a partition covering the stick, and set it to `8300 Linux filesystem`. I then make a FAT32 partition using

```
mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sdc1
```

as suggested.

I then extract the files. That should be it with a GPT partition i figured, but since it didn't work I also ran `makeboot.sh` according to the instructions:

```
The partition table of /dev/sdc is not for MBR (Master Boot Record). Its layout is:
Model: General USB Flash Disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 4009MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name              Flags
 1      1049kB  4009MB  4008MB  fat32        Linux filesystem  legacy_boot

This program is for making a bootable disk with MBR partition table.
For GPT disk, there is no need to run this program. Just make sure the partition is
FAT32 with ID=ef00 and all the files are copied on that. That's all.
Program terminated!
```

Still, the stick will not boot. I know BIOS is probing it, since I get the a message saying `This disk is not bootable`.

**What is `ID=ef00`?**

**What have I missed to make the USB bootable?**

---

Some more info:

```
$ ls -a
.  ..  amd64-release.txt  boot  Clonezilla-Live-Version
.disk  EFI  GPL  home  live  syslinux  utils
```

Comment: Your command works with `/dev/sdd1` but the message you show says `/dev/sdc`. Those are two different devices.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Thanks, that was a typo. Corrected it above now. All commands were run on the same device.

Comment: What is the output of `ls` at the mount point (when you mount the stick)?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani, thanks for writing. Please see edit of my original post.

Comment: You can just extract the ISO for UEFI boot if in an FAT32 partition with esp,boot flags. But for BIOS boot you have to install a boot loader to MBR. And if gpt you will need a bios_grub partition. In gidsk the code for esp flag is ef00 and for bios_grub is ef02. The actual code in system is a very long GUID with gpt partitioning. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table Almost all hardware in last 10 years is UEFI, so BIOS boot not as normal. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/bios.html I have only used gpt partitioning for new/changed drives for about 12 years.

Comment: @oldfred Thanks, I missed to set the partition type to `ef00`! However, even after doing that, the computer (which is not that old) doesn't recognize the drive as bootable. I also tried choosing the "boot from EFI-file" alternative in the startup menu, but when choosing the usb-drive it looks empy. I have confirmed that the files are actually there on the stick.

Comment: All external drives installer or full install directly boot from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. You do need some UEFI settings. Often easier with UEFI Secure boot off. And many need a setting on allowing USB boot or full USB support or similar setting.

Comment: @oldfred Thanks, I'll check the boot setting, that might be the problem.